# Get an element for an aggregation MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to get the value that results for an aggregation. If I print the aggregation with the code:

```
for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
System.out.println(result);
```

}

I get the result:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "532ae141675bfa1389f7d403"} , "leadTime_30" : { "date" : { "$date" : "2014-07-29T22:00:00.000Z"} , "value" : 113.4}}
```

I want to get the value of "value", but it's impossible. I can't use cursors, my mongoDB version is 2.4 and I cant update. Thankw for the answers!

SOLVED: Save the leadTime_30 as a DBOBject and do the get("series) thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a `DBObject` so you can just use `result.get("leadTime_30.value")`. If you want the aggregation to only return `value` you will have to change your aggregation (using `$project`).

Comment: with the update it's better :)

Comment: Yep missed that it was in the array.

Comment: I receive a java.null.pointer.exception. I tried that before ask here. My error code is this:

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at es.mongo.service.HistoryMongoService.getHistory(HistoryMongoService.java:133)
 at es.tp.gecko.model.ModelBuilder.createStatsModel(ModelBuilder.java:20)
 at es.tp.services.TPDataUserStories.getLeadTime(TPDataUserStories.java:114)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: I cant do that, there's no option to do two gets.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value you need to access it by `result.get("leadTime_30.value");`